# TextInputLayout как изменить цвет textColorHint если елемент активен

Tags: android, activity, android-themes

Здравствуйте! TextInputLayout как изменить цвет textColorHint если елемент активен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работало все нормально до тех пор пока не сменил тему в манифесте

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivitySettings"
            android:theme="@style/MyNoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivityIWaitOrder" />
```

Разметка TextInputLayout (на activity они все идентичны)

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/name_s1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:theme="@style/MyTextInputLayoutWhitwBG">
                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/editText_driveMarka"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:hint="Марка авто"
                    android:textColor="@color/colodDiv"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:theme="@style/MyEditText"
                    android:text="hello" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

файл styles.xml

```
 <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/NotCapsButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NotCapsButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

    <!--Floating label text style-->
    <style name="MyTextInputLayout" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">#AAAAAA</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colodDiv</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTextInputLayoutWhitwBG" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorGray</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorGray</item>
    </style>

    <!--Input field style-->
    <style name="MyEditText" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorGray</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>


    <!--RadioButton text style-->
    <style name="MyRadioButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colodDiv</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#242444</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1F1F3C</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorCenter">#4E4C8C</color>

    <color name="colorTextWorning">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorBackGroundTrans">#40ffffff</color>
    <color name="colorGray">#999999</color>

    <color name="colodDiv">#4e4c8c</color>
    <color name="colorTrans">#554E4C8C</color>
    <color name="colorWhite">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="colorText">#BCBEFF</color>
    <color name="accent_material_dark_1">#030ffc</color>
</resources>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Исправил тему и все заработало

```
<style name="MyTextInputLayoutWhitwBG" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorGray</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorGray</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```